# Why do I need to set the width to get the maximum size when it contains box horizontal glue in the panel that has a box layout?

Tags: java, swing, menu, awt, frame

I need to set this CBox (cricle by blue on the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NiMU.png)) to not max height and good width. But when I use setMaximumSize, which comes with two parameters, the first is width. I set it around 100 to 200, but it is not working out; it is still small. and when I use bookIDCBox.getMaximumSize().width, it works out. I don't know why I set the maximum width when it contains horizontal glue boxes in the panel.

This is my GUI:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/YmMZh41.png]

the panel has 2 horizontal glue boxes and CBox has mixumum size.
Code:

```
private JPanel buttonPanel() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 80));
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        buttonPanel.add(insertBtn = new JButton("Thêm"));
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        buttonPanel.add(resetBtn = new JButton("Xóa trắng"));
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        buttonPanel.add(removeBtn = new JButton("Xóa"));
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        buttonPanel.add(updateBtn = new JButton("Sửa"));
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        buttonPanel.add(saveBtn = new JButton("Lưu"));
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        buttonPanel.add(new JLabel("Tìm theo mã sách:"));
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        buttonPanel.add(bookIDCBox = new JComboBox<>());
        bookIDCBox.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(bookIDCBox.getMaximumSize().width, bookIDCBox.getMinimumSize().height));
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        insertBtn.addActionListener(this);
        resetBtn.addActionListener(this);
        removeBtn.addActionListener(this);
        updateBtn.addActionListener(this);
        saveBtn.addActionListener(this);
        return buttonPanel;
}
```

GUI with width of CBox 200

[image: https://i.imgur.com/h2UCoov.png]

`bookIDCBox.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, bookIDCBox.getMinimumSize().height));`

I need explain why maximum width size work... Thanks

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) section.

Comment: A BoxLayout will first try to display components at their preferred size. The maximum size is only used to allow the component to grow if there is extra space available to the panel.  I would suggest a FlowLayout would be easier to use since, by default, it will add 5 pixels of space between components. Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem if you need more help. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test the code posted.